# EF5 Code First The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I found several questions on here relating to this but I'm not quite there. I'm trying to add a second UserProfile property to the already existing CourseRegistration class. When I try to perform the migration I get "The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.CourseRegistrations_dbo.UserProfile_InstructorId"

I thought I could solve it with some fluent configuration but it had no effect. Based on what I've read I think the issue is that there is existing data that won't allow this.

Question 1: I don't completely understand what it's complaining about and would like to understand it better if anyone could shed some light. 
Question 2: Is there any workaround other than dropping the table or removing the data? I don't mind doing that this time, but I'm sure there are situations where that's not an option.

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class CourseRegistration
{
    [Key]
    public int RegistrationId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int? InstructorId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile user { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile Instructor { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks,

joel

Comment: can you show code of your model before adding midration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15087465/1814343), and try this:

```
public class CourseRegistration
{
   [Key]
   public int RegistrationId { get; set; }    
   public virtual UserProfile user { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("InstructorId")]
   public virtual UserProfile Instructor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just now noticed the response to this, sorry. 
I must have learned about that after I posted because I have another ForeignKey annotation in that same class now. But I had never gone back to this particular issue, so thanks!